# How to quickly check if contents of HDFS have changed?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to quickly (within a few ms) check if the contents of my HDFS have changed, so that I can run a more expensive (a few seconds) operation which caches the entire file tree. Is there a way to do this?

Right now, the easiest way (I think) to tell if anything on the FS has changed is to run

```
$ hdfs dfs -stat /
```

...which returns the timestamp (to the second) of the last modification time of the root directory. However, this isn't much faster than

```
$ hdfs dfs -ls -R /
```

...which is the command I use to build a cache of the file tree. Is there a faster way to check if HDFS has changed other than using `stat`?